# Why does this expression have a valid type?

Tags: haskell, ghci, applicative, lifting, derivingvia

Banging around in `ghci`, I happened to notice that the expression `(*) 1 [1..5]` apparently has a valid type.

```
:t (*) 1 [1..5]
(*) 1 [1..5] :: (Enum t, Num [t], Num t) => [t]
```

Apparently it is a list with several type constraints, including `Num [t]` which looks impossible to me, like it should give an error.

How is this the type of the expression? Why does `ghci`'s `:t` command not give an error here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's look at how these constraints come to be to explain the type.

### Numbers

In Haskell a literal number is replaced with a call to `fromInteger` (or `fromRational` if it has a decimal point or an 'e' in it). This way one can write '1' and have it be float or a double or an int or whatever. The type of `fromInteger` is

```
fromInteger :: Num a => a
```

So `1` gets desugared to `fromInteger (1::Integer)` which has type `Num t => t`

### Ranges

In Haskell the syntax `[a..b]` is converted into the call `enumFromTo a b` and the type is `enumFromTo :: Enum a => a -> a -> [a]`. Putting these together we get

```
[1..5] == enumFromTo (fromInteger 1) (fromInteger 5) :: (Enum a, Num a) => [a]
```

### Putting it all together

Now the type of `(*)` is `Num b => b -> b -> b` so we combine these all together to get:

```
(Num t,
Num a,
Enum a,
Num b,
t~b,
[a]~b) => b
```

Note that `a~b` means the types `a` and `b` are the same. Combining these gives the type

```
(Num a, Enum a, Num [a]) => [a]
```

Answer (score 11):

`Num [t]` is not just possible, it's easy:

```
import Control.Applicative
liftA0 = pure -- hobgoblins, simple minds, etc.
liftA1 = fmap
instance Num t => Num [t] where
    (+) = liftA2 (+)
    (-) = liftA2 (-)
    (*) = liftA2 (*)
    negate = liftA1 negate
    abs    = liftA1 abs
    signum = liftA1 signum
    fromInteger n = liftA0 (fromInteger n)
```

So it would be awful for GHC to produce an error instead of inferring that your expression could be well typed with an appropriate instance.

Of course, it would also be awful to ever write this instance in real code, but GHC shouldn't be in the business of passing judgment on code like we humans do.

Comment: A Num instance could be define for [] to behave like polynoms (ie having a infinite sequence of leading 0) which wouldn't be awful to write in real code.

Comment: `abs` and `signum` would be a bit awkward though.

Comment: @gallais The definitions don't need to be useful, just consistent. `signum x = [1]` and `abs = id` would probably suffice for most intended uses of such an instance.

Comment: Might as well be `undefined` in that case, no? At least you'll get a runtime error if you make the mistake of using these meaningless functions (`abs` and `signum` come with laws)

Comment: @mb14 I would argue that doing so would still be terrible; at least use a `newtype` to cover your shame.

Comment: @gallais Why would I want a runtime error? My definition obeys `signum x * abs x == x`; I claim this is at least consistent with any other instance of `Num`, whether or not it is useful to a user of such a polynomial encoding.

Comment: @david I think words like  awful and shame if not subjective deserve an explanation.

Comment: Can be [derived via `Ap [] a` now](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69154278/165806)

Answer (score 0):

This pattern of idiomatic/applicative lifting exists as [`Data.Monoid.Ap`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html#t:Ap) where `Ap [] a` specifies lifting operations with `pure`, `fmap` and `liftA2`: `(+) = liftA2 (+)`:

```
>> :set -XDerivingVia
>> :set -XStandaloneDeriving
>>
>> import Data.Monoid (Ap(..))
>>
>> deriving via Ap [] a instance Num a => Num [a]
>>
>> 1 * [1..5]
[1,2,3,4,5]
>> [100,200] * [1..5]
[100,200,300,400,500,200,400,600,800,1000]
```

The behaviour for lists is [derived via `Ap [] a`](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/deriving_via.html?highlight=derivingvia#extension-DerivingVia). You get different applicative behaviour through [`ZipList`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#t:ZipList)

```
>> import Control.Applicative (ZipList(..))
>> 
>> deriving via Ap ZipList a instance Num a => Num [a]
>>
>> 1 * [1..5]
[1,2,3,4,5]
>> [100,200] * [1..5]
[100,400]
```

Comment: OK, but how would you get `Enum` that way?

Comment: Idk about `Enum` instances for lists, but it can be derived via [`Generically`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/generic-data-0.9.2.0/docs/Generic-Data-Internal-Generically.html#t:Generically)